# vb.net System namespace conflict with sibling namespace

Tags: .net, vb.net, namespaces

I have a class `EventArgs(Of T)` in my solution.
This class is located in the namespace `Acme.Infrastructure.Interface`.
A class with the same name `EventArgs` exists in the `System` namespace.

In another project in my solution I have a class `Acme.BusinessModules.MyModule.MyClass`
When attempting to use the `EventArgs` class I have to fully qualify the class name or the compiler thinks I am using the `System.EventArgs` class.

My understanding of namespace resolution was that the compiler would first look for the class in the current namespace, and then its parents. It seems that the compiler checks in `System` before it checks in sibling namespaces.

Is it correct that `System` is checked before the sibling? Or is this behaviour caused by other issues (Imports order?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the namespaces involved:

- `Acme.BusinessModules.MyModule`
- `Acme.Infrastructure.Interface`

There's no reason why the compiler would look in `Acme.Infrastructure.Interface` when compiling a class in `Acme.BusinessModules.MyModule`. Now if the code you were writing were in (say) `Acme.Infrastructure.Interface.SomethingElse` then that would be a different matter - but here it looks like the compiler is doing absolutely the right thing. The fact that both namespaces start with `Acme` is neither here nor there.

As you yourself said:

> My understanding of namespace resolution was that the compiler would first look for the class in the current namespace, and then its parents.

The ancestor namespaces here are `Acme.BusinessModules` and `Acme` - *not* `Acme.Infrastructure.Interface`.

I would also *strongly* advise you *not* to create class names which conflict with those in `System`. It's really just asking for trouble.

Comment: Ok, was just my misunderstanding of the namespaces system then, time to do some reading.
The class with the same name was created by SCSF!

Comment: @DaSilva_Ireland: I've never used SCSF, but you should *absolutely* see if you can disable that class generation (or just delete it if it was a one-time thing). It will just cause you pain.