# How to avoid seemingly automatic reference of "parent" namespaces?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

I believe I have a fundamental misunderstanding of namespace hierarchy, causing almost the opposite problem to this question: [vb.net System namespace conflict with sibling namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155976/vb-net-system-namespace-conflict-with-sibling-namespace)

I have two .cs files containing the below:

**File 1**

```
namespace Parent.Math
{
    public class Foo { }
}
```

**File 2**

```
using System;
namespace Parent.Child
{
    public class Bar
    {
        public Bar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Math.Sqrt(4));           
        }
    }
}
```

**File 2** presents the error: `CS0234 - The type or namespace name 'Sqrt' does not exist in the namespace 'Parent.Math'`

Why does the compiler assume `Math` to be reference to the sibling namespace and not the member of the explicitly referenced `System` namespace? The behavior is as if parent namespaces are automatically referenced. Is this correct? I would of at least expected an ambiguity error.

Thank you.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that when searching for a name, it always starts from the current namespace.

Comment: *"The behavior is as if parent namespaces are automatically referenced. Is this correct?"* Yes.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(System.Math.Sqrt(4));`

Comment: @RufusL Thank you kindly. I assume therefore the only solution is fully qualified names or aliases?

Comment: Or change `namespace Parent.Math` to `namespace Parent.SomethingElseHere.Math`.

Comment: or put using `System;` inside the namespace. If you want to know the gory details, `14.5.3 Using namespace directives` in the ecma specs

Comment: @MichaelRandall That's new to me and resolves the issue, thank you! Any reason why this would be "bad practice"?

Comment: `Any reason why this would be "bad practice"?` Partly because it makes the code slightly harder to review (vs being explicit about `System`). But honestly, it is going to be hard to review regardless due to the clash.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Thank you for the input but my example was really just demonstrative. `Static` is not applicable for my use and I am aware of aliases. I just wanted to understand the behavior.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood i was a bit optimistic with the reference to ecma, the resolution is actually spread out of several topics. There are  2 schools on whether you should use contained using, or global using in the compilation unit. There are benefits to both,  I wouldn't consider either bad practice, as long as you were consistent.

Comment: [Language Specs 7.7 (Scopes)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#77-scopes) describe (7.7.1, second bullet) that any name defined inside namespace "N" will automatically be available to other members defined inside namespace "N" or in any nested namespace (starting with "N."). A common example of this is when you have types in "MyProject.Module" they are automatically available in "MyProject.Module.Tests" namespace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are in a namespace, the compiler always assume that you are in the parent namespace too.

Hence while being in `Parent.Child`, writing `Math`, the compiler search in `Child` and next in `Parent` and found `Math` as a namespace but no `Sqrt` type, so the error.

The compiler search like that and go up the chain of namespaces.

Without namespace, you are in `global`.

You can simply write:

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Math.Sqrt(4));
```

Or that in case of problem:

```
Console.WriteLine(global::System.Math.Sqrt(4));
```

You can also write:

```
using SystemMath = System.Math;

Console.WriteLine(SystemMath.Sqrt(4));
```

And since C# 6:

```
using static System.Math;

Console.WriteLine(Sqrt(4));
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of the solution options (aliases and fully qualified names). I was really asking to understand why parent namespaces were promoted above explicit references, or at least why no ambiguity error was thrown. I have my answer from the comments and your answer here will likely prove useful to someone.

Comment: Great, that's an answer now, thank you. Perhaps include the option of including the using statement within the namespace for completeness? As per @MichaelRandall comment.